# What does 'npm:' means?

Tags: npm, definition

I've started working on a project in my new workplace .

It's react project and has a package.json which has the dependencies like the one below.

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "gsap": "^2.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mobx": "^5.1.2",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.2",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "npm:@hot-loader/react-dom",
    "react-draggable": "^3.0.5",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.8.3",
    "react-id-swiper": "^1.6.9",
    "react-resize-detector": "^4.0.5"
},
```

For react-dom, the version is specified as "npm:@hot-loader/react-dom".
What does 'npm:' means?

My coworker guess it's the way that only yarn uses.

I wonder about this naming as 'npm install' doesn't install react-dom, but 'yarn install' install it.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Refer this link :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native

Comment: Searching for the package name soon gave me [this description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hot-loader#hot-loaderreact-dom) - it's explicitly replacing a built-in package with a version from `npm`, it seems.

Comment: @Ken Y-N Thank you for your answer. I've found that description before, but now it's clear to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this dependency is installed wrong it should be:

`react-dom@npm:@hot-loader/react-dom`

It's a yarn name resolution, so `@hot-loader/react-dom` would be installed instead of `react-dom@npm`